# Using a Future's response

Tags: scala, future

Hoping someone can offer an opinion on a solution for this issue I'm having.

I'll try to simplify the issue so save bringing in domain issues, etc.

I have a list of Optional strings. I'm using the collect method to basically filter out strings that don't exist.

```
names collect {
    case Some(value) => value
}
```

Simple enough. I'm homing to actually go one further. If a value is a None I'd like to call a function and use its response in place of the None. For example

```
names collect {
    case Some(value) => value
    case _ => getData(_)
}
```

The catch is the `getData` method returns a future. I understand that conventions for futures advise accessing the value within a callback, so something like the map method or on complete, but the issue is that I don't know if I need to call the `getData` method until I'm in the collect and have the value, so I can't simply wrap all my logic in a map method on getData. It doesn't feel like using Await and blocking is a good idea.

Any idea how I could reasonably handle this would be greatly appreciated. Very new to Scala, so I'd love to hear opinions and options.

EDIT:

I was trying to simplify the problem but I think I've instead missed out on key information.

Below is the actual implementation of my method:

```
def calculateTracksToExport()(
  implicit exportRequest: ExportRequest,
  lastExportOption: Option[String]
): Future[List[String]] = {
    val vendorIds = getAllFavouritedTracks().flatMap { favTracks =>
        Future.sequence {
            favTracks.map { track =>
                musicClient.getMusicTrackDetailsExternalLinks(
                  track,
                  exportRequest.vendor.toString.toLowerCase
                ).map { details =>
                    details.data.flatMap { data =>
                        data.`external-links`.map { link =>
                            link.map(_.value).collect {
                                case Some(value) => value
                                case None => getData(track)
                            }
                        }
                    }.getOrElse(List())
                }
            }
        }.map(_.flatten)
    }
    vendorIds
}
```

Comment: return a completed future if there is a value, and real future otherwise

Comment: The method I'm going to pass the list of names to is expecting a list of strings

Comment: What's the parameter to your `getData` method?

Comment: getData's just a placeholder really. In the real scenario I'm quite deep into a chain of maps, and it expects a case class extracted further up the chain.

Comment: I've added the actual method I'm experiencing issues with above so hopefully this will explain clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What's track variable?

Comment: @user3750194 i've suggested an edit to reformat the code and name some anonymous vals; please revert it if it misrepresents your intentions. i think it will help us to drill down to what you actually care about.

Comment: oh. looks like it's being rejected by @Helper. well, if you like it, feel free to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10615094

Comment: in general, i'd say you're trying to do too much, too compactly. name some of your anonymous `map` arguments. use a `val` or two to hold intermediate results (`val x=foo.bar; x.baz` rather than `foo.bar.baz` all the time) -- it often helps to give these things names for clarity *and* you can enforce a type on them as well if you're uncertain about how they will be inferred.

Comment: oh look - it was accepted. still, please revert it if i've mischaracterized your function.

Comment: No no that's fine! Thank you for clearing it up anyway, much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Future.sequence for collecting values:

```
def collect(list:List[Option[String]]):Future[List[String]] = Future.sequence(
  list.map {
    case Some(item) => Future.successful(item)
    case _ => getData()
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've added the actual method I'm experiencing issues with above so hopefully this will explain clearer what I'm trying to do. I'm already in a Future sequence.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped point me in the right direction. Ultimately I shouldn't of been trying to extract the future's result but instead wrap the string in a future. The result of this was obviously going to be a Future containing a list of Futures that contained strings. By mapping using future sequence and then running a flat map I was able to finally get a list of future strings. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If something can be in future, you will have to always treat it like future. So have sequence of Futures as return value:

```
def resolve[T](input: Seq[Option[T]], supplier: => Future[T]): Seq[Future[T]] = {
    input.map(option => option.map(Future.successful).getOrElse(supplier))
}
```

Usage example:

```
// Input to process
val data = Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(5))

//Imitates long-running background process producing data
var count = 6
def getData: Future[Int] = Future( {
    Thread sleep (1000)
    count += 1
    count
})


resolve(data, getData) // Resolve Nones
  .map(Await.result(_, 10.second)).foreach( println ) // Use result
```

Outputs:

```
1
8
2
7
5
```

http://ideone.com/aa8nJ9